# Area divide algorithm

Tags: algorithm

Is there any algorithm to find a distribution of area into n sub-regions, where each sub-region might have different area.

To formally put the problem statement: Suppose you have a rectangular plot. How will you divide the region into n rectangles. The sum of area of these sub-rectangles will be equal to original rectangular plot(So there wouldn't be any overlaps between the rectangles)
And the area of each of these smaller n rectangles is given before hand.
Restriction is on width of each sub-rectangle.
This subdivision has to be displayed on may be a computer screen which is divided into pixels. So I don't want any areas any dimension to be smaller than a pixel(or maybe 10), which might be of no use to display as such.

I was looking at [a rectangle packing algorithm here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-image/rectanglepacker.aspx) but this seems to be wasting space which I don't want. Does there exist any algorithm to solve this problem.

Backtracking doesn't seem to be a good solution in this case as the sub-rectangles area is only specified, not the dimensions, or is it?

Example 1:
[image]

Example 2:
[image]

Comment: If only the *area* of each sub-rectangle is specified, then the problem is easy to solve. Just divide the whole area up into strips, each of the correct area. In other words, each strip would be as wide as the entire land, but just narrow enough to create the correct area.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen My thoughts exactly, although I suppose that's too easy and that the question is missing some restriction...

Comment: You could get fancy though, and just each time you divided, you could divide across the other dimension. ie. first time you carved off enough along one dimension to hold the first rectangle, which leaves you with another piece along the same dimension. So for the next rectangle, you switch which dimension you carve in. Still, that would be easy as well. *as long as you only have the areas specified, and not their dimensions*

Comment: Well agreed to the point of dividing the original area along one dimension. But my bad, I did incorrectly phrase the question. The restriction is to the width of each such division. Let me edit the question

Comment: The restriction is on the minimum width or height of the divided rectangles, so that the areas as such are usable, may be to display on screen, or print

Comment: http://www.cs.umd.edu/hcil/treemap-history/index.shtml - enough resources and links to papers and research to keep you busy.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: I think that dividing on one dimension and then moving on to the other should work out fine.

Answer (score 0):

The [integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral) of a function is the area bound by the limits, the curve of the function, and the x-axis. Define one side of the rectangle as the x-axis, then find the boundaries for the others. There are plenty of numerical integration libraries around in the language of your choice.

EDIT: some difficulties in trying to illustrate in words...

Assuming, at least, that the containing rectangle has an area larger than the sum of the areas of the sub-regions; and there is no requirement of a certain order of containment:

1. Contain the largest sub-region first with edges on the axes.
2. Pick the next smaller sub-region.
3. Create the function (integral) to calculate the free area as seen from each axes.
4. With windows/limits equal to the length on the sub-region's sides (facing the axes), slide these windows along the axes away from the origin.
5. Create the function for finding the free space bounded by the outside arms of the cross formed by the windows as they slide along the axes. Efficiency in the use of space is found in the region where free space is minimal (differentiation).
6. Rotate the sub-region by 90 degrees and repeat from step 3.
7. Place the sub-region in the orientation and location where most efficient.
8. Repeat step 2. Stop when sliding windows report negative

free space for the entire domain (allocated space overlaps the placeholder made by the windows).

In theory, this will systematically try to squeeze in sub-regions. Sketch and pseudocode to follow if time permits.

Comment: Where do integrals come into this?